# remove logger from configuration

Tags: logback

When I use logback as logging framework, I add logger configuration on runtime for debugging. For example set "org.springframework" to debug level.

after I find the data I need I want to remove this configuration without restarting the application.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options depending upon how you want to modify the log level.

**First option - using logback.xml**

Logback xml provides an option to periodically scan the configuration. By setting that, you ask the logger framework to periodically update its in-memory setting to sync with the XML configuration. When you want to enable debug mode, XML configuration will look as below:

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">

<!-- Appender configurations here -->

<logger name="org.springframework" level="debug" additivity="false">
   <appender-ref ref="YOUR_APPENDER_NAME"/>
</logger>

<!-- Other logger configurations (including root) go here -->
</configuration>
```

After you complete your task, you can either delete that logger entry or set the level to ERROR to stop logging for that package.

**Second option - In-memory**

If you don't want to touch your logback.xml, but somehow handle it in runtime (say, using some REST APIs of you application), you may get the specific logger instance and set the level to DEBUG. Once you complete your activity, you may set the level to 'null' so that the level is inherited from the parent. Sample code will be as below:

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

.....

LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
Logger logger = context.getLogger("org.springframework");
logger.setLevel((Level.toLevel("DEBUG"));

// Do your task

logger.setLevel(null); // When we do this, level will be inherited from parent.
```

Answer (score 0):

logback has an option that allows periodic rescanning of the configuration file to look for changes.

```
<configuration scan="true"> 
  ... 
</configuration>
```

Comment: Yes I know I can edit the configuration file. is there a way to do that from code?

Comment: Yes. The logback documentation is quite good in describing how to do this.

Comment: You can execute `logger.setLevel( Level.DEBUG );` for the particular logger that you want to change the level on.